# string substitution in python - unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'

Tags: python, substitution, string-substitution

I'm stuck with a simple piece of code, I'm sure it's just a silly mistake, I hope someone can point it out to me. Here the code I have:

```
a = ['_a','_b','_c']
data_template = ['data%s']
for f in a:
    this_data = data_template % (f)
    print this_data
```

I just want it to print out

```
data_a
data_b
data_c
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Actually there is no need for passing a tuple `(f,)`, the string `f` itself is already enough. (EDIT: refers to a comment which seems to have been deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `string` for the template: `data_template = 'data%s'`

The `%` operator works on strings, not on lists.

Comment: FWIW, instead of the `%` operator you can also have a look at [str.format]( https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), it's more powerful and can some things that `%` operator can't.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes... unless you meant `data_template = '[data%s]'`?

Comment: no no it's all good now, for some reason I was putting `data_%s` into a list. worked it out now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the template inside a list, just do

```
data_template = 'data%s'
```

or

```
this_data = data_template[0] % (f)
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @plamut I also just figured this out the minute I posted it. wrong quotation marks, should be:

```
data_template = ["data%s"]
```

and not

```
data_template = ['data%s']
```

*note: this is also wrong*

should be

```
data_template = "data%s"
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference, Python treats single and double quotes the same. :)

Comment: Yeah, it happens, no worries. Anyway, I assume we've answered your question?